"comfortable", but in the conceptual sense
What is the best way to express in German that a concept is "uncomfortable", or that someone is "uncomfortable"/"not at ease" with a concept? For instance, the following two sentences:

"This option is uncomfortable, because it creates significant risks for the company". Is it OK to translate literally, for instance "Diese Option ist ungemütlich/unbequem, denn sie erstellt für die Firma deutliche Risiken." ?

"I am not comfortable/at ease with this option, because it creates significant risks for the company". Here it does not look like we can translate literally, meaning I can't really say "Ich bin ungemütlich mit dieser Option", right? Therefore, would something like "Ich fühle mich mit dieser Option unwohl, weil sie für die Firma deutlichen Risiken erstellt." work?



Example 1. seems ungrammatical to me. Surely comfortability is relative to a person and not universal? Then should it not be something like: "This option seems uncomfortable to me." Still, unless we are talking about chairs, it seems a strange thing to say.

@hkBst Thanks for your comment! Yes, there could be something syntactically strange here. But these are sentences you would definitely hear in English, rightly or wrongly.

"ungemütlich" or "unbequem" does not fit quite in either way. In this context "unangenehm" or "nicht wohl fühlen" or "unwohl fühlen" (like you suggest) are the way to go:
"Diese Option ist unangenehm, denn sie impliziert für die Firma deutliche Risiken."
"Ich fühle mich mit (oder bei) der Option nicht wohl, denn sie bedeutet/erzeugt/... signifikante Risiken für die Firma." or like you suggested "Mit der Option fühle ich mich unwohl, denn..."
Mind also that "Risiken erstellen" is not an appropriate fit here either as it means to create physically on purpose and/or present - but you want to say "create as a side effect of a(nother) course of action". Thus it has to be "erzeugt Risiken" or "erschafft Risiken" or simply implies risks ("impliziert Risiken").

First consider whether you shouldn't just simplify it - why do you need to put your personal comfort in at all? Just get to the risks right away:

Diese Option ist risikobehaftet für die Firma.

(or even simpler "riskant"). Then you can still follow up with a simple "ich bin dagegen".
If you do want to bring in something like "uncomfortable", I would suggest in addition to "unangenehm" also "unsympatisch" - literally meaning in English "unsympathetic".
You should also pick a suitable phrasing for the risks; idiomatic ones include

Diese Option ist mir unsympathisch, da sie erhebliche Risiken für die Firma nach sich zieht.

or

Diese Option ist mir unangenehm, denn sie stellt ein erhebliches Risiko für die Firma dar.


Thanks for your answer!
